# How do I get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x^*, y_0 + \Delta y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) + \epsilon$ using continuity?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Because the partial derivatives exist in $G$, the mean-value theorem says that there is a number $x^*$ between $x_0$ and $x_0 + \Delta x$ such that
>
> $u(x_0 + \Delta x, y_0 + \Delta y)-u(x_0,y_0 + \Delta y) = \Delta x \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x*, y_0 + \Delta y)$
>
> Furthermore, since the partial derivatives are continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$, we can write
>
> $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x^*, y_0 + \Delta y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) + \epsilon$

I'm having trouble understanding the following statement

> $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x^*, y_0 + \Delta y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0) + \epsilon$

How do we derive the previous equality using continuity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of continuity
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$$ since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$.

Regardless of continuity we can define the function $$\epsilon = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x^*,y_0+\Delta y)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) .$$
By the above mentioned continuity you get $\epsilon\to 0$ if $x^*\to 0$ and $\Delta y\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply an alternate expression for continuity of $\partial_x u$ at $x_0, y_0$. Rewrite the definition of continuity.